# How long does the closure compiler default.js last for?

Tags: javascript

I just minified a script using **[this](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home)** tool and noticed the line "The code may also be accessed at default.js". Here's a pic:
[image]

How long will this link stay good for? Is it safe for me to use this in my script tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To use the optimized code, you can cut and paste it into your source file, download the file into your directory, or link to the file directly in your script tag (**for up to one hour**).

This is from the help page on the link you posted.